# NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "POST / in SYmfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have an ajax posted form causing me to want to pull my hair having tried various answers based on almost similar problems here to no avail.

I have the following route in my routing.yml file

```
_save_profile:
pattern:    /register/save-profile/{data}
defaults: {_controller: MYBundle:Registration:saveProfile}
requirements:
    _method:  GET|POST
options:
    expose: true
```

and use the following code to post my form

```
var postData = $('#form').serializeArray();
$.ajax(
      {
     url: Routing.generate('_save_profile',{
         type: "POST",
         data : postData,
         }).done(function()
         {
            alert("Saved");
         });
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just omit the `_method` requirement and accept all methods? What version of Symfony are you using? The [HTTP method requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) syntax changed in 2.2

Comment: Looking closer, it looks like you just have a typo. Shouldn't it be `url: Routing.generate('_save_profile'), type: 'POST', ...`? Your code should actually trigger a JS error in your browser's console.

Comment: I'm using symfony version 2.4 and there's no javascript error, the url referenced works fine. Initially I had it without the _method and added it as part of the solutions i've been picking all over

Comment: Removed _method still no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need send form data through parameter `{data}` in route. If you want send form with ajax, so you need.

**Change route:**

```
_save_profile:
    pattern:    /register/save-profile/
    defaults: {_controller: MYBundle:Registration:saveProfile}
```

**Change js:**

```
var postData = $('#form').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
      url: Routing.generate('_save_profile'),
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      dataType: "json",
      success:
              function(result) {

                    console.log(result);

              },
      error:
              function() {
               alert('Error')
              }
    });
```

**note**: I don't use `FOSJsRoutingBundle` bundle for js routing. I always render route on template in data attribute. For example.

**html**

```
 <form type="POST" id="form" data-url="path('_save_profile')">
```

**js**

```
var url = $('#form').data('url');
```

**References**

1. **[How to implement a simple Registration Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html)**
2. **[FOSJsRoutingBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)**

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked like a charm!